# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. <to be read again>

Tags: capacity

In fact, I got this **error TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]** when I use \doublespacing of the package setspace and no PDF file is produced. But when I remove \doublespacing, there is no problem and the pdf file is produced. 
  N.B: My paper is a single column 12p. Only the nomenclatures are displayed 
  in a 2 columns. Here is the code

```
 \immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,3p,numbers,sort,compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\journal{ISA transactions}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{framed}  
\usepackage{nomencl}

\doublespacing
\makenomenclature%\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{\item[\textbf{Greek Symbols}]}{
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\item[\textbf{Subscripts}]}{}}}
\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{\footnotesize}
\begin{document}

 \begin{frontmatter}

\title{blablablablabal}








\begin{abstract}
blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  
blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  
blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla 
 blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  
blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  
blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla 
blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  
blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  
blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla 
blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  
blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  
blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla 
blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  
blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  
 blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla 
 \end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
blablabalabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blabla

\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}

blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  
blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  
blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla 
blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  
blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  
blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla 
blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  
blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  
blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla 
blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  
blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  
blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla 
blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  
blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  
blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla 
blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  
blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  
blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla 
blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  
blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  
blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla a  
blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla 
blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  
blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  
blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla 
blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  
blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  
blablabla 
\begin{framed}
\nomenclature[01]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[02]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[03]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[04]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[05]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[06]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[09]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[10]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[11]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[12]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[13]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[14]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[15]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[16]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[17]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[18]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[19]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[20]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[11]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[12]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[13]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[14]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[15]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[16]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[17]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[18]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[19]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[20]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba} 
\nomenclature[20]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[21]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[22]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[23]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[24]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[25]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[26]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[27]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[28]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[29]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[30]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[31]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[32]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[33]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[34]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[35]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[36]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[37]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[38]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[39]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[40]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[41]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[42]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[43]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[44]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[45]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[46]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[47]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[48]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[49]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[50]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[51]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[52]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[53]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[54]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\nomenclature[55]{$X_{1}$}{blablaba}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\printnomenclature[1.9cm]
\end{multicols}
\end{framed}
 blablablablablablablab blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  
 blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla 
 blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  
 blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  
 blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla 
 blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  
 blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  
 blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla blablabla  blablabla  blablabla 
 blablabla  blablabla  blablabla 
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Show a small  but complete example that demonstrates the error.

Comment: The paper is so long it won't show what I want

Comment: To debug your code we need to see the code. Move your document to some test folder and then start to remove things, until you get something that you can show here.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it's okay I have edited the post

Comment: The problem is obviously in `multicols` nested in `frame`.

Comment: @egreg but I need 2 columns for my nomenclatures

Comment: @kerdoujkardouj I can understand it, but I know of no method of framing a `multicols` environment that breaks across pages.

Comment: I don't see the point in framing a nomenclature. Why do you want  let it stick out like this? Is it the most important part in your article? But beside this: it is quite difficult to frame two column text. Inside multicols tcolorbox works more or less, but outside you would have to draw the frame manually by storing coordinates and then adding some backgroud pictures.

Comment: Will this work for one column ? Do you have a proposition ?

Comment: This question has been asked again, at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/531673 , and has an answer there.