# undefined control sequence when using \addchap

Tags: chapters

When I compile my thesis.tex file which is compiled fine including the `\addchap`, I noticed that I have used `\usepackage{unnumberedtotoc}`. When I want to use my thesis.tex file on another computer it says tex capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. When I uncomment `\usepackage{unnumberedtotoc}`, it says ! undefined control sequence  `\addchap`.
 Here I have pasted all the beginning of the packages that I have used in my thesis but I still get some problems in compilation, I don't know why, but I think if I can compile this code, then I can solve the problem  :

```
 \immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{30}{16}{12}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{array, nccmath}
 \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcolumntype{m}{>{\displaystyle}l}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{gensymb}
 \usepackage{empheq}
  \usepackage{mathtools}
  \usepackage{array}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.9}
  \newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{1.6em}<{$}}
  \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}c<{$}}
  \usepackage{makecell}
  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{subcaption}
  \usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
  \makenomenclature
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
  \usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
   \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{unnumberedtotoc} %https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc/
    \usepackage[automark,
    plainheadsepline,
    headsepline,
    plainfootsepline,
     footsepline,
    markcase=ignoreupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
   \clearpairofpagestyles
   \ihead*{\leftmark}
   \cfoot*{\pagemark}
   \setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scshape}
   \usepackage{titlesec}
   \graphicspath{{imagesthesis/}}
   \def\frenchlistfigurename{Liste des figures}
   \usepackage[a4paper,right=20mm,left=25mm,top=26mm, bottom=26mm]{geometry}
   \makeatletter
   \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
   {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
   % this alters "before" spacing (the second length argument) to 0
   \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
   %\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{20\p@}}{}{}{}% Removes space above \chapter head
   %\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{20\p@}}{}{}{}% Removes space above \chapter* head
   \makeatother
   \title {itle of the thesis}
   \titleformat{\paragraph}
   {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
   \titlespacing*{\paragraph}
    {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}



 \usepackage[thin, , thinc]{esdiff}
 \usepackage{subcaption}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{framed}  
 \usepackage{nomencl} 
 \setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip}\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
 \renewcommand{\cellset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}}

 \begin{document}
 \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.8}
%\noindent
 \doublespacing
 \maketitle
 \tableofcontents
%\listoffigures
 \addchap{Publications et communications}

 \section*{$\:$  a. Publications:}
 \section*{$\:$  b. Communications:}
 \addchap{Remerciements}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: \addchap is provided by unnumberedtotoc.

Comment: Please make the example more minimal and dhow the log file of the compile run that doesn't work.

Comment: You reported the same problem earlier. It never got solved https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488064/

Comment: Is there another way to add chapter without using \addchap

Comment: Yeah, sure. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @kerdoujkardouj You have asked this question twice and received an answer. It would be courteous to acknowledge that --- GOM.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `\addchap` does (`texdoc unnumberedtotoc` returns nothing) but I'm guessing that it generates an unnumbered `\chapter` and possibly adds it to the ToC. The general way of doing this is to use `\chapter*{Unnumbered title}` followed by `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Unnumbered title}`. I have reduced your MWE and added examples of `\addtcontentsline`.

```
% tocprob3.tex SE 531673 add to ToC???
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
% \addchap{Publications et communications}
\chapter*{Publications et communications}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Publications et communications}
\section*{$\:$ a. Publications}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{$\:$ a. Publications}
\section*{$\:$ b. Communications}
% \addchap{Remerciements}
\chapter*{Remerciements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Remerciements}
\end{document}
```

For more details about `\addcontentsline` one place to look, among others, is the documentation of the `tocloft` package (`> texdoc tocloft`).